# Packet loss in WinMTR test but not in PathPing?

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, packet-loss

I suspected some network issues with a host, so I ran both [WinMTR](http://winmtr.net) and [PathPing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958876.aspx) to test my connection to it.

The results were entirely different; WinMTR reported ~75% packet loss on each hop (except for my router), while PathPing reported none.

Is there a major difference in their test methods? If not, how come I got such different results?

I’m running on Windows 8.1, so maybe WinMTR doesn’t support it properly? (last release was 2011)

**Edit**

I figured that the only thing that might be different in their methods is that PathPing tests every hop separately, while WinMTR seems to test them simultaneously.

So, I ran a few cmd processes together to ping each hop (7 of them). Once all were sending pings, both the ping ratio of each of them went down significantly, and I actually stopped receiving replies (request timed out).

My next question is - what could this imply? Is this a "better" way of testing network issues?
Can this behaviour have an impact on actual applications (say, an online multiplayer game)?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of doing pings - it is probable that your provider is rate limiting or prioritizing ICMP but not UDP based pings or vice-versa, and you are getting different results.

I think you will find WinMTR uses UDP while Pathping uses ICMP.

It is unlikely that the problem relates to the version of Windows.